# Grid does not animate from collapsed to visible

Tags: height, blend, expand, visualstatemanager, fluid-layout

I'm currently trying to make a grid that animates from collapsed -> visible to notify the user that the save has been completed.  In Blend 4 I opened the project and created a usercontrol for the SaveNotifier so I can use it in other areas of this project and others.  I created the default to be collapsed and also created another state called "Complete" which has visibility set to Visible and has a timetrigger of 3 seconds which sends it back to the default state.  The transitions are set to transition over 1 second and use fluidlayout to show the animation between the states, but it does not show the animation between states.  Instead it just shows it as if there was no fluidlayout or transition time.

If someone would be so kind as to let me know if there is a problem with trying to do this or even show me how to do this it would be gre

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but when I put the grid inside of a new grid it started working. Seems as if you need to have a grid to be the full size for the animation to display.